# Image jumping down one pixel after loading

Tags: javascript, image

I am a complete novice on this and about 700 years too old to be messing about with anything else but a wood burning stove - BUT 
I wonder if anyone can see why the images are dropping 1, possibly 2 pixels after loading - apart from the first one. 
 I dont know where to look in the CSS or js files.
http://www.the-works.co/Mallorca/Pollenca2/finca2.html
What am I missing?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I watched the slider and there is no image jumping present that I can see... Browser = Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I watched through the images and didn't see any of them drop....

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this over the weekend.
It appears to have been the css  background-attachment: ; which was set to "fixed"

I have now left it blank and the images no longer drop and all display on all screen sizes that I have at my disposal in any orientation.

I am now trying to do the same for the type. I think it is in the webkit line somewhere